# Make div expand to a certain size

Tags: css, html

I have a div on my page, and I want to make it expand to a certain size and then stop. Right now I have...

```
div {height:300px; width:700px; overflow:auto;}
```

The overflow attribute makes it scroll, but until then, I would like it to expand with the content. I have a text box below this and it looks bad with a text box floating down part of the page. Is there a way to have both of these attributes? All of the hits I found on Google were about making it expand to fit the content. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `max-height`.

This will allow you to specify the maximum height the box can be and once it reaches this height it will scroll as you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want the div to have its height variable, depending on the size of content? Then just give height: auto instead of giving a fixed height of 300px. height: auto will adjust the height of the div based on the content size. Also define max-height property if you want to limit the maximum height the div can extend to.

Comment: No, I wanted a maximum height. The previous solution was quick, easy, and worked like a charm!